# Can I expand an HTML table to display more data from another django model?

Tags: html, jquery, css, django

I have the below HTML code, which creates a table by looping through the data from a Django SQL based model. I'd like to add a plus button to each row, allowing each to expand to show a few rows of data from a DIFFERENT model based on matching household id's. I've tried many different jquery functions along with adding the another body to the table with a new loop for the new model data, but I can't seem to get my desired result. Any help would be appreciated!

Example desired result:
[expanding row image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35H1C.png)

Code:

```
<div class="container" style="height:600px;width:1200px;overflow:scroll;max-height:500px">
    <table position="relative" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Household</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Account Number</th>
                <th>Basic Materials %</th>
                <th>Communication Services %</th>
                <th>Consumer Cyclical %</th>
                <th>Consumer Defensive %</th>
                <th>Energy %</th>
                <th>Financial Services %</th>
                <th>Healthcare %</th>
                <th>Industrials %</th>
                <th>Real Estate %</th>
                <th>Technology %</th>
                <th>Utilities %</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i in sectors %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ i.household }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.owner }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.account_num }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.basic_materials }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.communication_services }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.consumer_cyclical }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.consumer_defensive }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.energy }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.financial_services }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.healthcare }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.industrials }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.real_estate }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.technology }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

These are a few links i have tried:
https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/expand-collapse-in-html-table-rows-using-jquery/
https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/cam/979615#html-tab-view
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-html-table-expand-on-click-using-javascript/

Comment: Where is your js code ?

Comment: you might want to check out the jquery data tables https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html